# How to get scrollbar in monthview of FullCalendar

Tags: jquery, scrollbar, fullcalendar

I have many events for a day in monthview or i drag some other events to one day then the FullCalendar's height will be change.
I want to Fixed the fullcalendar's height and if one day have many enents then the vertical scroll-bar will be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

```
jquery fullcalendar scrollbar

  /* needed for modifying fullcalendar.css file */
    .fc-view {
        width: 100%; 
        height: 550px;
        position: absolute;
        bottom:0;
        overflow-y: auto;
        overflow-y: hidden;
        }
```